# Icefaces datetimeentry starting year as 00 instead 20 when i enter two digit year

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces

I’m using icefaces datetimeentry, everything works fine except one thing. When I enter two digit year like 19, it is showing as 0019 instead of 2019. Is there any help to convert it to 2019?
Do I need any converter or ajax call?

Comment: I think this is an issue that your loginc needs to handle. How can the software application 19 means 2019 or 1919 or 19 without some decision within the application.

Comment: Thanks for the reply dragonthought. So do I need a converter or an ajax call? I want this to be updated dynamically in calendar field. Could you please throw some light or code snippet.

Comment: Is there any ajax call or converter can help me here? User wants to see the converted value in calendar text box. So may be listener can help. Not sure which one to go ahead and code snippet really helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you must set the "pattern" attribute on the dateTimeEntry tag to a two digits year format (like "dd/MM/yy"). The default value for this property is "MM/dd/yyyy" (see [icefaces taglib docs](http://res.icesoft.org/docs/v4_latest/ace/tld/ace/dateTimeEntry.html) ) that yields 00yy when you set a two digits year (see [SimpleDateFormat Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)).